# Another word for 'audience'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How else can you refer to an audience, beside as *audience*, when you mean people who are reading a book?

I have thought of:

> audience
>
> readership
>
> readers/reader

etc

To clarify: I want words that refer to the audience of a text - doesn't have to be a book per se. So, in this sentence it would be "The simile makes the **_ feel happy" where _** is replaced with audience, readers, us, etc..

Comment: Target comes to mind

Comment: Synonym for audience might be **public**. Sometimes readers are classified according to their level of expertise into two groups: **general public** and **expert public**, but here the word *public* isn't a synonym for audience; it is used for a part of the population.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to books, the traditional way is to refer to "the reader" (singular).  This means the typical reader. Sometimes this phrasing is even used within a book (especially in a Preface)  to avoid saying *you*.  "the reader should note that...."  Likewise "the author" is sometimes used to avoid saying *I* or *we*.

Answer (score 0):

> An **audience** can be people watching a performance. The noun audience
>   can describe all the people watching a performance, or the part of the
>   general public interested in a **specific type of information** or
>   entertainment.

- people who are reading a book can be called an audience or simply **readers**.

Also, [**readership**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/readership) is when the audience is reached by written communications (books or magazines or newspapers etc.)

Answer (score -3):

You can think of lector which is a word you are looking for.

Meaning: Lector is a person who reads aloud. The word I am suggesting is specific to book audience which is you are looking for (not exactly).

For others who are asking for dictionary I had referred, I had searched on google for specific need. But for your shack of knowledge:

Oxford dictionary :

> A reader, especially someone who reads lessons in a church service.

Comment: Did you look up the word [*lector* in a dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/lector)? If so, and you (bizarrely) still think it's an appropriate answer, then please copy/paste the applicable dictionary definition into your answer here (with attribution to the specific dictionary you used, of course), so that OP and everyone else knows *why* you're suggesting it.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Good answers explain why a word is a good choice, using facts and not opinions.